# Manually send password resetting email for user in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

I have to create a simple user administration for a symfony 3 project.

One part of it is to start the password reset process for users.
(Yes, I know every user can trigger it himself but this is a request from our customer.)

Now I don't know how to start the process with a simple click in the admin interface for every user. Is there a method or a service in the UserBundle I can use?

Answer (score 4):

There is no `all in one` method but this can be achieved by:

```
if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
    $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
}

// send email you requested
$this->mailer->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);
// this depends on requirements
$user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
$this->userManager->updateUser($user);
```

with proper dependencies set.

Comment: So you have to rip it out of `sendEmailAction` in `ResettingController`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a service based solution written with Symfony 4.1 you can use without having to call in services form the container via `get()`

First you have to add an alias to services.yaml because the FOS mailer can't auto-wire:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer:
    alias: fos_user.mailer.default
    public: true
```

With that in place you can create the below class as service:

```
namespace App\Service; # change to your namespace

use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Class UserPasswordResetService
 */
class UserPasswordResetService
{
    /**
     * @var Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    /**
     * @var TokenGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $tokenGenerator;

    /**
     * UserPasswordResetService constructor.
     *
     * @param Mailer               $mailer
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Mailer $mailer,
        UserManagerInterface $userManager,
        TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator
    )
    {
        $this->mailer         = $mailer;
        $this->userManager    = $userManager;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     */
    public function resetPassword(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        // send email you requested
        $this->mailer->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);

        // this depends on requirements
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

}
```

Assuming you then add that service to a class via DI you can use it like this within a given method:

```
$this->passwordResetService->resetPassword($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information Kamil provided, this would be a full working function

```php
        /**
         * Sends the user a new password
         *
         * @Route("reset_password/{id}", name="user_reset_password")
         * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
         *
         * @param User $user
         * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
         */
        public function resetPasswordAction(User $user)
        {
    
            if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
                /** @var $tokenGenerator TokenGeneratorInterface */
                $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
                $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
            }
    
            $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);
            $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
            $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
    
            $this->addFlash('notice', "User {$user->getFullName()} got an email for resetting his password!");
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_index');
    
        }
```

Comment: Nowadays it would be better to use dependency injection to pass the dependencies to a service instead of fetching them via `get()`. Benefit of that is, for example, that you can use it independently of the controllers.